# Disable past date in check-in project

Tags: javascript, java, html, date, datepicker

Doing a hotel project where I need to disable past dates of the check-in and check-out.

on the code:

> input type ="date" name="from">
>   input type ="date" name="to">

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO is not a "write my code" service. Please post what you have tried so far - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Im not entirely sure on what you want though.  Disable the dates how?  Can you PLEASE be more spesific

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use jQuery to disable the past dates.
The following link may help you.

https://codepen.io/ahmetcadirci25/pen/NpMNzJ

Following code in HTML file

```
<input type="text" id="date" data-provide="datepicker">
```

Following code in .js file

```
  var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());

$('#date').datepicker({ 
    startDate: date
});
```